# fullcalendar scheduler columnFormat & slotLabelFormat

Tags: fullcalendar, scheduler

I am using fullcalendar scheduler and trying to set timeformat on the timeline to be in 24:00 format not in 12am or pm format.

The default timeline view has 12am/pm format and the threeday timeline has an extra row on top for the day http://fullcalendar.io/scheduler/ .

I think that the `columnformat` could be the key here. but unfortunately when i use `slotLabelFormat:'H:mm'` to get the timeline show 24:00 format, the columns displaying the date disappear on the 3 day view.

Is this a bug or am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how it works correctly:

```
           views: {
            timelineThreeDays: {
                type: 'timeline',
                slotLabelFormat: [
                'ddd D/M',
                'H:mm'
                ],
                columnFormat: 'ddd D.M',
                duration: { days: 3 }
            }               
        },
```

Comment: SlotLabelFormat worked for me. Not sure why columnFormat never worked though.